# Convert varchar to Integer for Calulation

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have a table with a column. The column holds information on customer locations using a grid system. So, our HQ is at `0,0` and our customers approx location in miles from the HQ is stored the same way e.g. `-1,9` etc. I am using the data type `Varchar` to store the grids.

I have been trying to write a query to extract the number of locations less than 5 miles from our HQ. But I seem to keep getting rather arbitrary results. Do I need to convert the grids to an int and remove the comma somehow? Or am I doing something else fundamentally wrong.

Comment: The problem is the table schema. You are storing both longitude and latitude in the same column, which would be fine if you where using a [spatial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) data type, but is wrong when you are using varchar. You should change the table's structure.

Comment: You cannot compare strings like that: you would need to break the string up into two parts (either side of the comma) and convert them to int and compare. Have you considered storing the X and Y values in separate columns as ints? that would make comparisons like this much easier.

Comment: An additional reference to `ZoharPeled`'s comment, see also [Spatial Types - geography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/spatial-types-geography?view=sql-server-2017). As already stated you should choose the correct data type for the data that you are storing. A geographic location should not be modeled as a string (varchar).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema issues aside, we can make this work, though performance might suffer. The examples I've provided makes an assumption from your example that the coordinates are always stored as two integers separated by a comma(,).

The first example leverages `PARSENAME` to split the coordinates for comparison. `PARSENAME` isn't really needed for just a question of "within 5 miles", but if you wanted more granularity of direction, then `PARSENAME` at least gives you certainty of your ordinals.

In the second example I used `STRING_SPLIT` to get the same results.

(one thing to note, you said "locations less than 5 miles" and between -5 and 5 will include locations AT 5 miles as well.

```
/* Build out the table */
CREATE TABLE Client
(
    Client VARCHAR(100)
    , Client_Location VARCHAR(12)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Client
(
    Client,
    Client_Location
)
VALUES
('HQ','0,0')
,('Cust1','-1,9')
,('Cust2','7,11')
,('Cust3','-5,5')
,('Cust4','4,1')
,('Cust5','5,6')
,('Cust6','6,5')


/* Ex 1 */
SELECT 
    *
FROM dbo.Client
WHERE
    CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Client_Location,',','.'),2) AS int) BETWEEN -5 AND 5
    AND CAST(PARSENAME(REPLACE(Client_Location,',','.'),1) AS int) BETWEEN -5 AND 5

/* Ex 2 */
SELECT 
    Client
    , Client_Location
FROM dbo.Client
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Client_Location,',')
WHERE 
    value BETWEEN -5 AND 5
GROUP BY Client, Client_Location
HAVING COUNT(client) = 2
```